# CursorLoader with emails and phones

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I need to get a Cursor loader with the list of emails and phones of each contacts like:

> Juan Perez  | juan.perez@gmail.com
>
> Juan Perez | juanito@gmail.com
>
> Juan Perez | +56912345678

Actually I have this:

```
CursorLoader(getActivity(),
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
{
    Contacts._ID,
    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI : Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;,
},
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1",
null,
Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
);
```

I'm actually using this on a Loader Manager and the cursor is made on the onCreateLoader method
but this just show the list of all emails of each contact